# Fusionchart does not display from database mysql

Tags: php, mysql, fusioncharts

I wanted to know why my chart is not working. I have included the `FusionCharts.php` and other necessary files in the project, and using the code below. The page comes up on my browser, but rather than displaying the chart it gives a `No data to dispay` error. What could be the problem? Regards

```
    <?php
    //We've included ../Includes/FusionCharts.php and ../Includes/DBConn.php, which contains

    include("Includes/FusionCharts.php");
    include("Includes/DBConn.php");
    ?>
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>
        FusionCharts Free - Database Example
        </TITLE>

        <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript" SRC="js/FusionCharts.js"></SCRIPT>
        <style type="text/css">
        <!--
        body {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
        }
        .text{
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
        }
        -->
        </style>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>

    <CENTER>
    <h2><a href="http://www.fusioncharts.com" target="_blank">FusionCharts Free</a> -Database and Drill-Down Example</h2>


    <?php
        //In this example, we show how to connect FusionCharts to a database.
    //For the sake of ease, we've used an MySQL databases containing two
    //tables.

    // Connect to the DB
        $link = connectToDB();

// Fetch all factory records

        $strQuery = "select SUM(quantity) AS SUM, YEAR(datePro) AS YEAR FROM factory_output GROUP BY YEAR(datePro ) ";
        $result = mysql_query($strQuery) or die(mysql_error());

    //$strXML = "<graph caption='Factory Output report' subCaption='By Quantity' pieSliceDepth='30' showBorder='1' showNames='1' formatNumberScale='0' numberSuffix=' Units' decimalPrecision='0'>";

        $strXML = "<chart caption='Annual Revenue - last 3 years' numberPrefix='$'>";

        //Iterate through each factory

            while ($ors = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

        //Generate <set name='..' value='..' />  
        $strXML .= "<set label ='" . $ors['YEAR'] . "' value='" . $ors['SUM'] . "' />";
                }
//Finally, close <graph> element

        $strXML .= "</chart>";

//Create the chart - Pie 3D Chart with data from $strXML

    echo renderChart("charts/FCF_Column3D.swf", "", $strXML, "FactorySum", 650, 450);

        mysql_free_result($result);



        mysql_close($link);




    ?>
    <BR><BR>
    <a href='../NoChart.html' target="_blank">Unable to see the chart above?</a>
    <H5 ><a href='../default.htm'>&laquo; Back to list of examples</a></h5>
    </CENTER>
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

Comment: Please don't use mysql_* functions because they are deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: Did you try debugging by `print_r` or by `var_dump` the data in `$result` variable to check if you are receiving the data and you are parsing it correctly? And as the above commenter said use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no issue in the code and it should work fine. But can you generate the XML data and check if the returned XML format is correct as per the chart rendered?

It could be the following scenarios why the error message is appearing instead of the chart:

- Your XML data doesn't contain any data that could be plotted by FusionCharts XT. In this case, your XML just contains the chart or dataset tags without any data between them.
- You might be rendering a single-series chart and providing data in multi-series format or vice-versa. In this case too, you'll get a "No data to display" message.

Comment: I realised the problem was from the sql statement which i have corrected. But now the graph displays, but shows only one bar, instead of four bars. i would wonder why only one bar displays correctly. could it be from the sql statement or the php?